# how to get the Userid in GET method in Django Rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to pass the requested "userid" to the Stored Procedure but I couldn't able to get the  requested "userid" in GET method. SP is working fine when I entered user id directly

views.py:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def ClaimReferenceView(request, userid):
    
    try:
        userID = Tblclaimreference.objects.filter(userid=userid)
     
    except Tblclaimreference.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
       
    
        user = Tblclaimreference.objects.get(userid=self.request.user.id)
        print(user)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[sp_GetClaims]  @UserId= %s',(user,))
        result_set = cursor.fetchall()
        print(type(result_set))
        response_data = []
        for row in result_set:
            response_data.append(
                {
                    "Number": row[0],
                    "Opened": row[1], 
                    "Contacttype": row[2], 
                    "Category1": row[3],
                    "State": row[4], 
                    "Assignmentgroup": row[5], 
                    "Country_Location": row[6], 
                    "Openedfor": row[7],
                    "Employeenumber": row[8], 
                    "Shortdescription": row[9], 
                    "AllocatedDate": row[10]
                } 
            )

        return Response(response_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        
    elif request.method == 'POST':

        serializer = ClaimReferenceSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

models.py:

```
class Tblclaimreference(models.Model):
    taskid = models.IntegerField(db_column='TaskId',  primary_key=True) 
    userid = models.IntegerField(db_column='UserID')  
    internaldescription = models.CharField(db_column='Internaldescription', max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)  
    additionalcomments = models.CharField(db_column='Additionalcomments', max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass a `Tblclaimreference`, not a user id. You can use:

```
cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[sp_GetClaims]  @UserId= %s',(userid,))
```

If you want to use the `.pk` of the logged in user, it is:

```
cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[sp_GetClaims]  @UserId= %s',(request.user.pk,))
```

Comment: How could I able to get only the requested user id consider that above method have no userid parameter was passed?

Comment: @imran_44: you can work with `request.user.pk` for the user id as is specified in the second code fragment. If you always use the request user, it is also better to remove the `userid` parameter from the function and the URL pattern.